# Programmatically Set Partner of Record for Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I am looking for a way to programmatically set the partner of record for an Azure subscription.  Currently, the only method appears to be through the UI:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2015/01/19/microsoft-azure-and-partner-of-record.aspx

Is there a way to do this through an API, powershell, or Azure command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new Az Module to support this: [Az.ManagementPartner](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.ManagementPartner/0.7.2)

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Get-AzManagementPartner

New-AzManagementPartner -PartnerId 12345

Update-AzManagementPartner -PartnerId 12345

Remove-AzManagementPartner -PartnerId 12345
```

All from here: [Link a partner ID to your Azure accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/link-partner-id)